# how to add character when type datetime input html js

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with input type = "date"

```
<input type =  "date" or "datetime-local" />
```

when the user selects the time on the calendar it will take more time than typing, i had an idea like this but it seems too difficult for me

when user type two character day(dd), it will add "/" to input, two character next (month mm) will add "/", and year like this

```
<input type = "number" value="11/08/1999" />
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Bare in mind this might result in confusion between `dd/mm/yyyy` and `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: I was just saying that if you have any users from, e.g. the USA, they may not enter it in that format, which is one reason most date pickers show some form of calendar.

Comment: Testing this on the browser I am using (MS Edge) you don't need to add the slash (/) characters when typing - the browser handles it for you

Comment: i just code this web for my company, user is almost employee in my company (don't worry)

Comment: Most of the employees at my company use phones with chrome and safari browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another user has mentioned, the input element itself will add "/" to the input.

However, if you log the value of the date input, the default date format is this: `yyyy-mm-dd`

If you want to reformat the date to this format: `dd/mm/yyyy`

Then you can do something like the example below:

```js
var dateInput = document.querySelector('#date')
var output = document.querySelector('#output');
var dateButton = document.querySelector('#dateButton');

function displayFormattedDate() {
  console.log('Default date output is: ' + dateInput.value)
  
  //convert output to date string
  var date = new Date(dateInput.value)

  //get dd +1 for timezone offset
  var dd = date.getDate() + 1

  //get month +1 for timezone offset  
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1

  //get full year
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear()

  //concat date variables to dd/mm/yyyy format
  var fullDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy

  //
  output.innerHTML = 'Reformatted date output is: ' + fullDate
}

//apply displayFormattedDate function to button
dateButton.addEventListener('click', displayFormattedDate)
```

```css
input{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<span>Enter Date: </span><input id="date" type="date" /><button id="dateButton">Add Date</button>
<br/><br/>
<p id="output"></p>
```

If input `type="date"` appears different in your browser, you can use input `type="number"` with a custom solution.

I've provided a small example in the snippet below but you will have to add extra validation to ensure date is entered properly.

```js
//declare vars
var mm = document.querySelector('#month')
var dd = document.querySelector('#day')
var yyyy = document.querySelector('#year')
var output = document.querySelector('#output');
var dateButton = document.querySelector('#dateButton');

function displayFormattedDate() {
  //combine values from inputs into full date format
  var fullDate = mm.value + '/' + dd.value + '/' + yyyy.value
  //some minimal validation to check date format
  if (mm.value.length !== 2 && dd.value.length !== 2 && yyyy.value.length !== 4) {
    output.innerHTML = 'Please enter valid date.'
  } else {
    //display date if format is correct
    output.innerHTML = fullDate
    var date = new Date(fullDate)
    console.log(date)
  }
}

dateButton.addEventListener('click', displayFormattedDate)
```

```css
input {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Enter Date: </p><input id="day" type="number" placeholder="day" /> / <input id="month" type="number" placeholder="month" /> / <input id="year" type="number" placeholder="year" /> <button id="dateButton">Add Date</button>
  <br/><br/>
  <p id="output"></p>
</div>
```

Or Option 3 is to just use input `type="text"` with replace and regex. The input below will not allow letters to be entered but will still require additional validation to ensure a proper date is being entered.

```js
var dateInput = document.querySelector('#date')

function addSlashes(e) {
  dateInput.value = e.target.value.replace(/^(\d\d\/\d\d)(\d+)$/g, '$1/$2').replace(/^(\d\d)(\d)$/g, '$1/$2').replace(/[^\d\/]/g, '')
}

dateInput.addEventListener('keydown', addSlashes)
```

```html
<span>Enter Date: </span><input id="date" maxlength=10>
```

Comment: My browser chrome in xiaomi 11t of me when run your code not type number, it just choose datetime calendar

Comment: I've added a new example above. Additionally, I also made a small change to the first example. Try running the first example again too and let me know if the input still appears as a calendar.

Comment: Also added a third option with regex and replace. I will say that it's not ideal to get a date without a proper date input because it adds extra steps of validation to ensure the date is being entered properly. That being said, if my answer helped solve your problem, please remember to upvote and click the ✓ symbol next to my answer to mark it correct :)

Comment: tks you, it really what i need

Comment: sr, i can't up vote u, because i just have 11 reputation